# Apache POI Event user model reads Timestamp value as a double

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an excel file where there is a timestamp column filled in with value
5/31/2011  5:49:44 PM
I am reading this excel file using POI Event Model. (the implementation is same as explained at http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf - "XSSF and SAX (Event API)")
The above timestamp value is read as 40694.74287037037 and I do not know why.
I am unable to format this value back to the Date-Time format.

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is entirely as expected. The Microsoft Excel file format stores all datetimes as fractional dates since 1900/01/01 or 1904/01/01, depending on a flag set in the file (the 1904 date window flag). So, when you read the raw value back, 6pm on the 1st of January 1900 should come back as `1.75`.

If you're using the UserModel code, there are plenty of helpers available to turn that back into a Date. In the Event Model, you have to spot that yourself (by checking the formatting), then call the conversion yourself.

The class you'll want is [DateUtil](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DateUtil.html), especially methods like [DateUtil.getJavaDate(double)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DateUtil.html#getJavaDate%28double%29)

Apache POI provides a number of examples of doing things like this, I'd suggest you review something like [XLS2CSVmra](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/hssf/eventusermodel/examples/XLS2CSVmra.java) for a guide.

Also, if all you want is the time, with no regard to the day, take the non-integer remainder and that's your fraction of the time through the day. For the current hour (round down), you'd do something like:

```
double date = cell.getNumericCellValue(); // 1.76
double time = date - ((int)date);
int hours = time * 24; // 18
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `date - ((int)date)`?

Comment: What's a negative time between friends? ;-) Fixed, ta!

Comment: Super thanks Gagravarr, will give it a try and let u know if it solved what my application is expecting

Answer (score 0):

I used the DateUtil.getJavaDate(double) solution suggested by @Gagravarr. 
I just kept an additional check in case someone has saved the date in String format and POI reads the same.
It worked perfect. Thank you all for all your valuable suggestions.